# android listview item mask when pressed

Tags: android, listview, imageview

the effect I want to achieve:

normal:[image]

pressed:[image]

notice the imageview is masked too when pressed, so apparently setting the layout background to a selector xml will not solve the problem

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a semi-transparent selector (e.g. a color with alpha) and set `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in your `ListView`. The list will draw selector above and you will achieve effect you need.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for! thank you very much! I forgot "drawSelectorOnTop"

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

1. Let your child parent be a FrameLayout
2. one child will be your current view, other will be  an empty view with attribute match_parent, match_parent with background and alpha required in your picture
3. Initially it will be hidden, on press child just make this view visible and vice versa.

Hope it help.

Comment: so you mean set a OnTouchListener on view ?

Comment: I'd like to know if there's way to achieve this by using selector xml

Comment: You said you don't want selector in your question.

Comment: sorry I mean setting the layout background to a selector xml will not solve the problem, but I'd be glad if there's any way to solve this by using selector, it's simple and easy to use